# How to prevent bitbake from looking for mirrors for specific host?

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

I am building a system image with yocto where some of the recipes reference software that is hosted on out private git repository server (let's call it `repo-host`). The checkout works fine, but bitbake always tries to first access the `downloads.yoctoproject.org` mirror instead of our own server.

In the `log.do_fetch` of the recipe, this behaviour can be seen in log entries like the following (hostname and repo name anonymized, but the rest is unchanged):

```
DEBUG: Fetching http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/mirror/sources/git2_repo-host.path.to.the.repo.git..tar.gz using command
'/usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 -nv --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -P /home/amu/projekte/yocto/motec-yocto/build/downloads 'http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/mirror/sources/git2_repo-host.path.to.the.repo.git..tar.gz''
```

**Question:** Is there a way to make bitbake globally avoid the mirroring mechanism only for certain hosts?  If not, is there a way to do that per recipe?

Ideally, the mirrors would not be contacted for all sources that are fetched for git URLs starting with a specific hostname (like `git://repo-host/...`). All other sources (the kernel, gcc etc.) should still use the mirrors.

Comment: Sorry for being light on the details, but I think the information provided should be enough to be able to answer such a general question. If not, I will of course amend the question :-)

Comment: you can specify the download directory path in conf file. Once the source downloaded, it will always refer local downloaded path instead of looking yocto mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the [PREMIRRORS](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PREMIRRORS) feature, the URLs you are seeing are probably coming from distro configuration you use (e.g. poky.conf). You can set (or prepend) the value of PREMIRRORS to a local download site or an empty string if it's important to you that these external pre-mirrors are not tried. You should be able to do this in your distro configuration, local configuration or in individual recipes.

Comment: So there is no way of configuring bitbake to automatically assume `PREMIRRORS=""` for all recipes where the source is fetched from our own `repo-host`? I will try setting the variable in the respective recipes, since I only want to disable the mirrors for our own software. Will try later and accept if no better way comes up :-)

Comment: What is the issue with adding your own premirror as the first one for the whole distro?

Comment: I want to preserve the original setting for all the original recipes but never try to fetch our own software from the yoctoproject premirror (and not set up my own mirroring infrastructure). Wouldn't setting `PREMIRRORS=""` simply disable mirroring for all recipes, and appending another premirror not avoid the premirror for our own software?

Comment: If you need to be 100% sure that bitbake never ends up trying to fetch your software from yoctoproject.org, then you probably do need to set PREMIRRORS to empty (or your own site) in the recipes or globally. Prepending your premirror site as the first one would also work _if_ you can guarantee that the premirror always has the version that is being fetched... otherwise bitbake may try yoctoproject.org.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it in a recipe and it works. For convenience, I added a `no_source_mirrors.bbclass` where I set (PRE)MIRRORS to the empty string and that is inherited by all "private" recipes. Feel free to add that option to your answer if you like :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can allow known hosts only with `BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS`

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS